# My Next JS app is not displaying the search results page when user enters a query - useRouter()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm developing a search app with Next js. I have 3 files in my app directory - layout.js, page.js, and searchResults.js

Code in layout.js

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'xyz Search',
  description: 'xyz Search',
}
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
 return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Code in page.js

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function SearchPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const handleSearch = () => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      const url = `/search?term=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}`;
      router.push(url);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      handleSearch();
    }
  };

  return ( //**some styling**//
  );
}
```

Code in searchResults.js

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

export default function SearchResultsPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { term } = router.query;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <p>You searched for: {term}</p>
      {/* Add your search results rendering logic here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I ran this on my local machine 3000. Its renders the page.js perfectly. But after a user inputs a search query it returns 404.

I tried many different things, but just cannot make the app to render the searchResults.js page after a user inputs a search query. Not sure where the problem lies. I haven't changed anything else in the vanilla Next Js project set-up. I have a feeling this error might have something to do with routing. I read that Next js automatically handles routing. Not sure if that holds in my case.

EDIT

Based on the suggestions given, I have updated the project directory. Now my app directry is as follows:

```
app > layout.js
app > page.js
app > search > index.js
app > search > searchResults.js
```

The code in my index. js file is as follows:

```
import { Link } from 'next/link';
import SearchResultsPage from '.';

export default function SearchResultsPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <Link href="/search">
        <a>Go to Search Page</a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Its still giving me a 404 error message for search results. It still can't seem to route to the search results page. Haven't change anything else in any other code

Comment: you need to have searchResults.js in an index file so your app structure should be 'app/search/index.js' for it to find the page. Then in the index.js file you can do export default SearchResultsPage;

Comment: tried it. Updated my code with the changes. Still 404 error message. Will appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry they changed it to page.js instead of index.js. see the docs here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/defining-routes#creating-routes

Answer (score 0):

this is happens because maybe you push query in string
use this
router.push({
pathname : `search`,
query : {term : "test"}
})
this will push url query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).